# Why is Color.colorToHSV and HSVToColor inaccurate?

Tags: java, android, colors

I am writing an Android game. In the game, different colored blocks will fall to the ground. When two blocks with the same color are on top of each other, they will merge into one block that is in a darker color. However, I observed that the blocks with the same color do not merge sometimes. After some debugging, I found that they are actually in slightly different colors: -16757700 and -16757444. I used `Color.colorToHSV` and `Color.HSVToColor` to make the color darker as you can see in my code below (The `checkLanded` method). So I think there must be something wrong with those two hsv methods. Here is my code (Actually I don't think there is anything else wrong with the code, you can just look at the `checkLanded` method. But I pasted the other code because the problem might not be where I think it is. Just almost scroll to the bottom and you will see the `checkLanded` method):

```
package com.shades;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;

import com.shades.util.BlockView;
import com.shades.util.Timer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class Block {

    private static Random r = new Random ();
    private static HashMap<Integer, Float> colorValuesMap;

    @IntDef ({LEFT, RIGHT})
    public @interface Direction {}
    public static final int LEFT = -1;
    public static final int RIGHT = 1;

    static {
        colorValuesMap = new HashMap<> ();
        colorValuesMap.put (4, 0.1F);
        colorValuesMap.put (3, 0.3F);
        colorValuesMap.put (2, 0.5F);
        colorValuesMap.put (1, 0.7F);
        colorValuesMap.put (0, 0.9F);
    }

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int color;
    protected Timer timer;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    private void setY(int y) {
        Block[][] matrix = Game.getInstance ().getBlockMatrix ();
        matrix[this.x][this.y] = null;
        this.y = y;
        matrix[this.x][this.y] = this;
        BlockView.updateViews ();
    }

    private void setX(int x) {
        Block[][] matrix = Game.getInstance ().getBlockMatrix ();
        matrix[this.x][this.y] = null;
        this.x = x;
        matrix[this.x][this.y] = this;
        BlockView.updateViews ();
    }

    private void setXY (int x, int y) {
        Block[][] matrix = Game.getInstance ().getBlockMatrix ();
        matrix[this.x][this.y] = null;
        this.y = y;
        this.x = x;
        matrix[x][y] = this;
        BlockView.updateViews ();
    }

    public int getColor () {
        return color;
    }

    public Block(int x, int y) {
        setXY (x, y);
        this.y = y;
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        hsv[0] = Game.getInstance ().getHueNumber ();
        hsv[1] = 1F;
        hsv[2] = colorValuesMap.get (r.nextInt (4));
        color = Color.HSVToColor (hsv);
        BlockView.updateViews ();
        timer = new Timer (new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                moveDown ();
            }
        }, 1000, true);
    }

    private void moveDown () {

        //if reached bottom
        if (getY () == Game.MATRIX_HEIGHT - 1) {
            timer.stopTimer ();
            Game.getInstance ().nextBlock (r);
            return;
        }
        color = Game.getInstance ().getBlockViewMatrix ()[x][y].getColor ();
        Block[][] matrix = Game.getInstance ().getBlockMatrix ();
        if (checkLanded (matrix[x][y + 1])) {
            Game.getInstance ().nextBlock(r);
            return;
        }


        setY (getY () + 1);
    }

    private boolean checkLanded(Block blockBelow) {

        //if it can merge into another block
        float[] currentHSV = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV (color, currentHSV);//here is the possible inaccurate method
        if (blockBelow != null &&
                blockBelow.getColor () == color &&
                currentHSV[2] != colorValuesMap.get (4)) {
            Color.colorToHSV (blockBelow.getColor (), currentHSV);
            currentHSV[2] -= 0.2F;
            blockBelow.color = Color.HSVToColor (currentHSV); //here is the possible inaccurate method
            selfDestroy ();
            timer.stopTimer ();

            //if the block below is not the block at the bottom
            if (blockBelow.getY () != Game.MATRIX_HEIGHT - 1) {
                blockBelow.checkLanded (Game.getInstance ().
                        getBlockMatrix ()[blockBelow.getX ()][blockBelow.getY () + 1]);
            }

            return true;
        }

        //if a block is touched
        if (blockBelow != null &&
                blockBelow.getColor () != color) {
            timer.stopTimer ();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void selfDestroy () {
        Game.getInstance ().getBlockMatrix ()[x][y] = null;
        BlockView.updateViews ();
    }

    private boolean checkPositionValid (int x, int y) {
        return !(x < 0 || x >= Game.MATRIX_WIDTH ||
                y < 0 || y >= Game.MATRIX_HEIGHT)
                && Game.getInstance ().getBlockMatrix ()[x][y] == null;

    }

    public void moveHorizontally (@Direction int direction) {
        if (checkPositionValid (x + direction, y)) {
            setX (x + direction);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me whether `Color.colorToHSV` and `Color.HSVToColor` are inaccurate or where else did I do wrong?

Just to let you know, `Game.getInstance().getHueNumber()` returns 167 if that helps

Comment: HSV representation uses `float`s. If you convert between `int` based RGB and HSV you're generally going to lose some precision. If you want accurate unchanging representation you should stick with RGB.

Comment: But how can I increase the darkness of the color in RGB? @Cinnam

Comment: To make RGB color darker you can do integer division of the R,G,B components by some constant. That will preserve hue and saturation. Ideally something like `newR = oldR * 75 / 100` to get 75% of the brightness. Same for G, B.

Comment: (by "integer division of the R,G,B components by some constant" I meant decrease the R,G,B components by the same percentage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a custom color class for this, where I would keep the accurate color information and only converted to another format if needed for the output. The conversion woudn't matter in this case because the converted values wouldn't be used for comparisons.

Something similar to this should solve your problem:

```
class CustomColor {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private static final int DARKNESS_LEVEL_COUNT = 5;
    private static final float[] DARKNESS_LEVELS = new float[] {0.9f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 0.1f};
    private static final float SATURATION = 1f;

    private float hue;
    private int darknessLevel;

    public CustomColor(float hue) {
        this.hue = hue;
        darknessLevel = RANDOM.nextInt(DARKNESS_LEVEL_COUNT - 1); // I'm guessing you don't create the darkest blocks
    }

    public int getColor() {
        float[] hsv = new float[] {hue, SATURATION, DARKNESS_LEVELS[darknessLevel]};
        return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
    }

    public boolean equals(CustomColor other) {
        return (hue == other.hue) && (darknessLevel == other.darknessLevel);
    }

    public boolean darken() {
        darknessLevel++;
        return darknessLevel == DARKNESS_LEVEL_COUNT - 1; // are we at max darkness?
    }
}
```

I don't know how you pick *hues*, but you could probably use a similar array approach as with darkness here.

Comment: But it still uses floats which means it is still inaccurate, right?

Comment: @Sweeper It uses floats, but they keep the value you give in the constructor. The key is that you don't compare floats that are the result of some conversion calculation. Still, you could have a `Map` or `array` of *hues* and index them in a similar way as `darknessLevel` indexes *darkness* here. Then you would just compare `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I found a solution for this. From @Cinnam 's comments, I know that HSV colors use `float`s and they are inaccurate. RGB is is not a good idea for me because I cannot easily know the hue.

According to *Code Complete 2nd Edition* by Steve McConnell, Section 12.3:

> ... One Effective approach is to determine whether the values are close enough. Typically, you'd write a equals() function that returns true if the values are close enough and false otherwise.

And I think that the two slightly different colors are "approximately equal" so I wrote a method like this:

```
private boolean intColorEquals(int color1, int color2) {
    final int MAXIMUM_ERROR = 1000;
    return Math.abs (color1 - color2) < MAXIMUM_ERROR;
}

private boolean floatEquals (float a, float b) {
    final float MAXIMUM_ERROR = 0.05F;
    return Math.abs (a - b) < MAXIMUM_ERROR;
}
```

And I replaced all the comparisons between colors and that between floats.

I really don't know whether an answer to my own question should be in a style  like this. So if I did anything wrong, please tell me.